# Using the Matrix.RotateAt in C#

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing, serial-port

I am attempting to rotate a gauge based on data that I am acquiring from a Serial Port. The Serial communications are working well and now I am having issues making the gauge rotate. I am now trying to make the image rotate with a slider bar and I am still having no luck. I currently have a timer implemented to trigger every 100 ms and run this code. However when I move the sliderBar nothing happens to the image on the screen. The reason I am using a timer is because that is what I will be using for my final implementation. Using a timer to trigger the UI update instead of the Serial event makes the application run much more smooth.

As always any help is greatly appreciated!

in the constructor...

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
        imgpic = (Image)pictureBoxBase.Image.Clone(); // This is storing an image in a picture box...
        foreach (int rate in baudRates)
        {
            brbox.Items.Add(rate);
        }
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Interval = 100;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();

        com.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(OnReceived);
    }
```

Then in the timer event...

```
   void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) // Again it is initially drawing the picture, but it does not rotate with the statusBar
    {

        Point test = new Point(0, 0);
        Image img = new Bitmap(400, 400); 
        pictureBox1.Image = img;
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
        Matrix mm1 = new Matrix();
        mm1.RotateAt((trackBar1.Value),new Point( 0,0),MatrixOrder.Append);
        GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
        gp.Transform(mm1);
        gp.AddPolygon(new Point[] { new Point(0, 0), new Point(imgpic.Width, 0), new Point(0, imgpic.Height) });
        PointF[] pts = gp.PathPoints;
        g.DrawImage(imgpic, test);
        pictureBox1.Refresh();

    }
```

Comment: As a side, timer.Start() is the same as timer.Enabled = true (MSDN: Setting Enabled to true is the same as calling Start, while setting Enabled to false is the same as calling Stop. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.enabled.aspx)

Comment: Ok, do you have any ideas as to why it's not rotating?

Comment: This took me a while to notice, but you don't appear to draw the path at all... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawpath.aspx

Comment: It is also important to perform the transformation of gp after adding the polygon. I wasn't sure about this but I just tried and it is necessary. (swap these lines around: gp.Transform(mm1); gp.AddPolygon(new Point[] { new Point(0, 0), new Point(imgpic.Width, 0), new Point(0, imgpic.Height) });)

Comment: Ok thank you! I am new to using any kind of graphics in my programs, could you perhaps show me what I need to change>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22205/discussion-between-visualmelon-and-vrknight)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key issues are:

- Not actually drawing the path you produce
- Not rotating the polys you add to the path (must apply transform *after* adding them)

Lots of potential for memory leaks here - objects with unmanaged components (Graphics, GraphicsPath, Image, and Matrix objects here) need to be disposed so that underlying Windows objects can be deleted nicely (.NET can't do this for you).

Fixed up code:

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        pictureBox1.Image.Dispose(); // dispose old image (you might consider reusing it rather than making a new one each frame)

    Point test = new Point(0, 0);
    Image img = new Bitmap(400, 400); 
    pictureBox1.Image = img;
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);

    Matrix mm1 = new Matrix();
    mm1.RotateAt((trackBar1.Value), new Point( 0,0), MatrixOrder.Append); // note that the angle is in degrees, so make sure the trackbar value or input is suitably scaled

    GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
    gp.AddPolygon(new Point[] { new Point(0, 0), new Point(imgpic.Width, 0), new Point(0, imgpic.Height) });
    //PointF[] pts = gp.PathPoints; // not needed for this task

    g.DrawPath(Pens.Black, gp); // draw the path with a simple black pen
    g.Transform = mm1; // transform the graphics object so the image is rotated
    g.DrawImage(imgpic, test); // if the image needs to be behind the path, draw it beforehand

    mm1.Dispose();
    gp.Dispose();
    g.Disose(); // prevent possible memory leaks
    pictureBox1.Refresh();
}
```

I think this ought to work, if it still has issue, comment here and I'll modify it if need be.

(Edit: looks like there is a lot of stuff to dispose that I didn't quite expect)

Comment: I was actually wanting to rotate the image imgpic, is that possible? This does rotate the triangle though! Thank you for this!

Comment: Do you want to rotate everything by the same angle? If so, you can tranform the graphics object itself, which will transform everything you draw to it. This you do _before_ any drawing, however. g.Transform = mm1;

Comment: I only want to rotate the image imgpic

Comment: Then draw the path, then transform the graphics object, then draw the image. (Edited code in answer to suit your needs)